# How can I use the sigil_p (~p) to create asset URLs which contain the digest hash?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to improve this working code to make it more idiomatic. I wish to refactor it and use `~p` if possible.

I added this config (the `cache_manifest` bit) to my `dev` environment (it was in `prod` by default) so I can test the behavior while developing:

```
config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/cache_manifest.json",
  url: [path: "my-app"],
```

```
animal = Enum.random(["cat", "dog", "zebra"])

full_path =
  static_url(
    MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
    "/images/animals/#{animal}.jpg"
  )
```

The result (which is correct), is:

```
"http://localhost:4000/my-app/images/animals/cat-09d70aa13c48ad427298cfd9d7fe8440.jpg?vsn=d"
```

Note that `my-app` is the `path` I configured, I want it to be reflected as well.

Using the sigil version returns an error:

```
~p"/images/animals/#{animal}.jpg"
```

```
** (ArgumentError) path segments after interpolation must begin with /, got: ".jpg" in "/images/animals/#{animal}.jpg"
```

My current code works as expected, but I'd like to see if this is a `sigil_p` bug or is there another way to make it work using `~p`, which would be the ideal way for me.

### Summary (requirements):

- Refactor the code using `Phoenix.VerifiedRoutes.static_url/2` and change it to `~p`.
- Make the digest hash appear at the end of the generated URL.
- Include the base path.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your error is a `sigil_p` bug.  The docs discuss some of the restrictions for interpolation into `~p` strings:

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.VerifiedRoutes.html#module-tracking-warnings

When you have interpolation problems, the docs seem to suggest that you should do the following :

```
p_for_animal("cat"), do: ~p"/images/animals/cat.jpg"
p_for_animal("dog"), do: ~p"/images/animals/dog.jpg"
p_for_animal("zebra"), do: ~p"/images/animals/zebra.jpg"
p_for_animal(_), do: no path
```

However, I was unable to get any path of the form `"/images/*"` to give me a warning.  The only time I got warnings was when I tried paths like `"/non/existent/1"`.  It seems that `~p` does not verify routes to `"/images"`